# draw a major arc and fill it with a gray color

Tags: tikz-pgf, technical-drawing

I am trying to draw the major sector below:

[image: output]

I have made some progress with the following code, but not quite what I want as I am having trouble filling the last bit of the sector.

```
\documentclass[]{article}
\usepackage[margin=0.5in]{geometry}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\renewcommand{\thesection}{\arabic{section}}
\usepackage{booktabs, makecell, multirow}
\usepackage{stackengine,graphicx,xcolor}
\usepackage{lscape}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows}
\usepackage{flexisym}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes.geometric}
\usetikzlibrary{decorations.markings}
\newenvironment{tightcenter}{
\setlength\topsep{0pt}
\setlength\parskip{0pt}
\begin{center}}{\end{center}}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=1.2]
%cylinder
\draw[black,thick,dotted] (0,0) circle (1.3cm);
\fill[fill=black,opacity=0.8] (-0.2,0.2) circle (0.8mm);
%\fill[fill=black,opacity=0.8] (+0.2,0.2) circle (0.8mm);
\fill[fill=black,opacity=0.8] (-0.2,-0.2) circle (0.8mm);
\fill[fill=black,opacity=0.8] (+0.2,-0.2) circle (0.8mm);
%\draw [thick,dashed] (7,1) -- (8.2,1);
%\draw[thick,<->](3.4,-1.52) to node[fill=white] {$3.5$ cm} (3.4,-3.22);
\draw [thick,domain=95:355] plot ({1.3*cos(\x)}, {1.3*sin(\x)});
%
\draw [thick,domain=94:270,fill=gray,opacity=0.5] plot ({1.3*cos(\x)}, {1.3*sin(\x)});
%\draw [thick,domain=270:300,fill=red,opacity=0.5] plot ({1.3*cos(\x)}, {1.3*sin(\x)});
\draw [thick] (1.3,-0.15) -- (0,0) -- (-0.15,1.3);
%\\
\draw [thick](0,0)++(0:0.25) arc (0:79:0.3);
\node[above] at (0.4,0.2) {$50^{\circ}$};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image: current output]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You could draw your outline and fill it in one line of Code with `\draw [thick, fill=gray, fill opacity=0.5] (0,0) -- (95:1.3) arc (95:355:1.3) -- cycle;`.

```
\documentclass[]{article}
\usepackage[margin=0.5in]{geometry}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\renewcommand{\thesection}{\arabic{section}}
\usepackage{booktabs, makecell, multirow}
\usepackage{stackengine,graphicx,xcolor}
\usepackage{lscape}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows}
\usepackage{flexisym}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes.geometric}
\usetikzlibrary{decorations.markings}
\newenvironment{tightcenter}{
\setlength\topsep{0pt}
\setlength\parskip{0pt}
\begin{center}}{\end{center}}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=1.2]
%cylinder
\draw[black,thick,dotted] (0,0) circle (1.3cm);

\fill[fill=black,opacity=0.8] (-0.2,0.2) circle (0.8mm);
\fill[fill=black,opacity=0.8] (-0.2,-0.2) circle (0.8mm);
\fill[fill=black,opacity=0.8] (+0.2,-0.2) circle (0.8mm);

\draw [thick, fill=gray, fill opacity=0.5] (0,0) -- (95:1.3) arc (95:355:1.3) -- cycle;

\draw [thick](0,0)++(0:0.25) arc (0:79:0.3);
\node[above] at (0.4,0.2) {$50^{\circ}$};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

The `(95:1.3)` moves you to the starting point of your outer perimeter, after that you draw the arc `arc (95:355:1.3)` with the starting angle of 95, end angle of 355 and a radius of 1.3. Then you don't have to fiddle around with sine and cosine.

I hope I didn't misunderstood, what you wanted to achieve!

Best Regards!
Frieder

**EDIT**: I changed `opacity=...` to `fill opacity=...`. Otherwise, the dotted line would shine through.

And here is a picture:
[image: picture]